# Find the specific line with character in specific position

Tags: search, find, grep

Finding the line with a specific character before the last character. Suppose, I have the following string

```
1. addar_ctrl1,1,2,0,0,1
2. addar_ctrl2,3,2,0,1,0
3. addar_ctrl3,4,8,0,0,0
4. addar_ctrl4,2,6,0,1,1
```

I want to grasp the line contains '1' in the 2nd last position in each row.

Expected output:

```
2. addar_ctrl2,3,2,0,1,0
4. addar_ctrl4,2,6,0,1,1
```

Comment: do you know regular rexpressions?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yes, I know, but failed to catch this mach.

Answer (score 2):

Use a negated `:global`, e.g.:

```
:v/,1,[^,]*$/d
```

Comment: Should I use `:g!/,1,[^,]*$/d`? I used it and got the expected matched output in separate that contains only the matched lines.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :).

Comment: The `:g` command actually stands for [`:global`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal), not `:grep`. While using `:g!` is of course possible, I see it much more often used as `:v` (for `:vglobal`) and I typically recommend using that one (since it's also shorter, easier to type.)

Comment: @filbranden: noted, thx.

Answer (score 2):

This is the one situation where using an external tool such as `awk` can help, particularly if you're trying to match something on a column in the middle (not close to the start or end), or when the rows don't have the same number of columns, etc. While using a regex to match those is almost always possible, it's often not the most convenient approach.

You can shell out to `awk` from Vim to filter the buffer and keep only the lines with a 1 in column 5, with:

```
:%!awk -F, '$5 == 1'
```

You can also use a more restrictive range (in place of `%`) if you don't want to filter the whole buffer. Or use a Visual selection, in which case when you press `:` Vim will automatically fill in `:'<,'>` which is the range corresponding to the lines in the last Visual selection.

Note that `!` is a special character in a `:!` command in Vim (, it's replaced with the previous external command executed), so you need to escape it if you use it. For example, to use an external `awk` to filter the contents and keep only lines where the fifth field is *not* zero, you should use:

```
:%!awk -F, '$5 \!= 0'
```

Note the backslash escaping the `!`, to prevent Vim from expanding it.

Comment: Good call @Quasímodo! That's indeed likely to come up when using an external `awk` and is not obvious to spot... I updated the answer to mention this case. Thank you!